# Swift - Array of PDF pages to NSData

Tags: arrays, macos, swift, pdf, nsdata

I am working on a Mac OS X PDF splitter program.

A PDF is loaded by the user, then some pages are selected to create a new PDF file, only with those pages.

I am using `pdfThumbnailView.selectedPages()` to select the pages, which return an array of PDF pages that correspond to the thumbnails selected in the thumbnail view.

Now I want to turn this into a NSData object, in order to build a new PDF with `PDFDocument(data *data*: NSData!)`

I tried to use `NSKeyedArchiver`, but my array is not compliant to `NSCoding`, making the program crash.

Does anyone have a good alternative to this ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those who are going to see this, here is the solution I found: I used the `func insertPage(page: PDFPage!, atIndex index: Int)` method of `PDFDocument` to build a brand new PDF doc, in a for-in loop.

No need to use serialization, which was a bit overkill for what I wanted to do.